# В чем смысл интерфейсов?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
interface IDrawable
{
   void Draw();
}
```

Его реализовывают классы `Rectangle` и `Circle`. Почему бы просто не создать абстрактный класс `Shape` и в нем определить метод Draw, а позже унаследовать его в классах `Rectangle` и `Circle`?

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Какой-нибудь `Cat` тоже может быть  `IDrawable`, но при этом он не является  `Shape`

Comment: В том что вы не привязываетесь к реализации.

Comment: Основная идея: отделение различных уровней абстракции друг от друга. В вашем учебном примере это, возможно, не так видно, но схема работает. Например интерфейс между слиентом и сервером передает данные и клиенту все равно как он это делает. Т. Е. Мы меняем модель передачи данных без изменений в поведении клиента.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Наследования стараются по возможности избегать в пользу какой-нибудь агрегации, так как иерархию тяжело менять и поддерживать.
2. Не всегда классы, которые могут быть взаимозаменяемыеми (одинаковый набор методов) выводятся из одной иерархии и , как следствие полиморфизм не работает.

   В этом случае нам на помощь приходят интерфейсы с помощью которых мы можем "привить" классу некоторый контракт в обход наследования и использовать разные реализации интерфейсов => полиморфизм снова работает.

Конкретно в вашем примере у вас может быть 2 параллельных иерархий:

1. Иерархия примитивных фигур
2. Иерархия Windows Control

Пометив обе этим интерфейсом, вы сможете их обрабатывать одинаково.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "дорогой" операцией? Интерфейсы работают как минимум не быстрее наследования (абстрактных) классов, нам все так же нужно привязывать указатели через vtable. У интерфейсов эта операция может быть немного сложнее из-за реализации множества интерфейсов. Но в основном "скорость" в обоих случаях +- одинаковая.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker имеется ввиду, что иерархию потом тяжело менять. Ну т.е захотел ты древо наследования поменять и все, что ниже поломалось. А интерфейсы более легче в этом.

Comment: А, ну с этим тогда согласен, слово "дорого" смутило :)

Comment: `и , как следствие полиморфизм не работает` раскройте пожалуйста мысль. Не очень понятна взаимосвязь работы принципа с реализацией.

Comment: @zalex ну типа так как нету какого-то общего типа, то ты не можешь передать переменную в метод, где используется общий базовый тип.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему бы просто не создать абстрактный класс Shape и в нем определить метод Draw, а позже унаследовать его в классах Rectangle и Circle?

Можно, никто не запрещает. И для небольших программ может быть вполне уместно (хотя это далеко не лучшая практика). Но завтра придет ТЗ добавить в программу прорисовку эллипса. Послезавтра заказчик скажет: "Переделайте редактор в 3D, я хочу рисовать гиперболоиды".

Отсюда вопрос: откуда этот класс `Shape` будет знать, как ему рисовать эллипсы и гиперболоиды? В него такую задачу никто не вкладывал на момент его написания. В итоге получается такая картина, что при добавлении каждой новой фигуры будет необходимость редактировать реализацию класса `Shape`.

Даже если говорить о окружностях и прямоугольниках... Для прорисовки окружности нужны координаты центра и радиус, для прорисовки прямоугольника - (обычно) координаты левого верхнего угла и ширина с высотой. Объединять их в один метод с параметрами достаточно сомнительная идея. Делать базовый класс, содержащий приватными полями координаты центра, радиус, координаты левого верхнего угла, ширину и высоту - идея еще сомнительнее. До боли режущее глаз нарушение [принципа единственной ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).